# Printing all longest matching substrings

Tags: c++, vector

I have an assignment for finding all of the longest matching sub-strings between the strings "B D C A B A" and "A B C B D A B".  There are a lot of partial solutions to this online but none that do what I need them to.  I created this to find one longest matching sub-string, but I need to be able to find all of them, there should be 6 in total.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void myLMS(string one, string two);

int main()
{
    string s1 = "ABCBDAB";
    string s2 = "BDCABA";
    myLMS(s1, s2);
    return 0;
}
void myLMS(string one, string two) {
    vector<vector<char>> lms;
    vector<char> one_lms;
    for (int i = 0; i < two.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < one.length(); j++) {
            if (two[i] == one[j]) {
                one_lms.push_back(two[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    lms.push_back(one_lms);
    for (int i = 0; i < lms[0].size(); i++) {
        cout << lms[0][i];
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to continue with this method and get the outcome I'm looking for or is another approach needed?

Edit:  I found this solution https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-longest-common-subsequence-set-2-printing/
but I'm not really interested in just copying from a program as that doesn't really help me.  It also only accomplishes half of what I'm trying to do.

From the assignment prompt it looks like the first three strings printed from this example are there as well as the same three only backwards.  Reversing the strings doesn't get those backwards sub-strings so how would they be calculated?

Comment: You need to rethink this, and find another approach. If the first string contains "abcdef", the second one "fef", `one_lms` ends up containing "eff". Then `one_lms` gets added to `lms`, How does that help you in your stated goal, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is incomplete by quite a bit.  Here's some pseudo-code to help you get started.

```
for each character in string 1
  for each character in string 2
    if char_1 == char_2
        possible substring match 
            do the next chars match?
                yes
                    there is a substring - now find longest
                no
                    no substring match, continue the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what's the need to solve it in this manner since your input strings are fixed you run for loops from first char of one string to last -1 char and and run another nested for loop for each subsequent characters if a match is found like the program of finding out common substring that all of us have done in the beginning.

Comment: We don't do it that way because it is really slow.